# How to refresh ActionBar navigation item during traversing the Fragment back stack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

The Android 4.1 `ActionBar` provides a useful navigation mode as a list or tab. I am using a `SpinnerAdapter` to select from three fragments to be displayed in view `android.R.id.content`. 
The `onNavigationItemSelected()` listener then inflates each fragment to the view and adds it to the back stack using `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)`.

This all works as advertised, but I don't know how to update the `ActionBar` to reflect the current back stack.  Using the `ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position)` works but also triggers a new `OnNavigationListener()` which also creates another `FragmentTransaction` (not the effect I want). The code is shown below for clarification.  Any help with a solution is appreciated.

---

```
public class CalcActivity extends Activity {
private String[] mTag = {"calc", "timer", "usage"};
private ActionBar actionBar;

/** An array of strings to populate dropdown list */
String[] actions = new String[] {
    "Calculator",
    "Timer",
    "Usage"
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    // may not have room for Title in actionbar
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
    // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
    new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        actionBar.getThemedContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        android.R.id.text1,
        actions),
    // Provide a listener to be called when an item is selected.
    new NavigationListener()
    );      
}

public class NavigationListener implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private int firstTime = 0;

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPos, long itemId) {
        mFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag[itemPos]);

        if (mFragment == null) {
            switch (itemPos) {
            case 0:
                mFragment = new CalcFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                mFragment = new TimerFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                mFragment = new UsageFragment();
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }               
            mFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
        }

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if (firstTime == 0) {
            firstTime++;
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag[itemPos]);
        } else {
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag[itemPos]);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        ft.commit();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected : " + 
                actions[itemPos], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }       
}

public static class CalcFragment extends Fragment {             
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calc, container, false);
    return v;
    }   
}

public static class TimerFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timer, container, false);
    return v;
    }   
}

public static class UsageFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_usage, container, false);
    return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

1. Create a boolean to track when you are selecting a navigation item based on the back button:

   ```
   private boolean mListIsNavigatingBack = false;
   ```
2. Override onBackPressed, in the override, check if the backstack has items, if so handle yourself, if not call the superclass:

   ```
   public void onBackPressed() {
       if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
           mListIsNavigatingBack = true;

           //You need to get the previous index in the backstack through some means
           //possibly by storing it in a stack
           int previousNavigationItem = ???;

           getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(previousNavigationItem);
       }
       else{
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Inside NavigationListener, handle the `mListIsNavigatingBack` state, manually pop the back stack and unset the state:

   ```
   if(mListIsNavigatingBack){
       if(fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
           fm.popBackStack();
       }
       mListIsNavigatingBack = false;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions which I implemented with a stack.  Given the added complexity and unique UX, I am having second thoughts about this design pattern. Is it better to never addToBackStack() when using ActionBar navigation?

Comment: The list navigation does make it complicated.  Typically the back stack is used more for swapping out fragments within your current view, so perhaps your use case could be simplified by just re-attaching the fragment that's in the background.